Probability of winning by drawing tiles that sum to 10
I have a bag containing 8 numbered tiles: $\{5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 2, 1\}$. I draw tiles randomly without replacement. I win if at any point the sum of the tiles drawn equals 10. What is the probability of winning?
My Attempt:
The possible ways to sum to 10 are:

$5 + 5 = 10$
$5 + 3 + 2 = 10$

Step 1: Counting favorable outcomes

For $5 + 5 = 10$: There are 4 tiles labeled $5$, so the number of ways to choose two of them is $\binom{4}{2} = 6$.
For $5 + 3 + 2 = 10$: The number of ways to choose one $5$, one $3$, and one $2$ is $4 \times 2 \times 1 = 8$.

Thus, the total number of favorable outcomes is:
$$
6 \ (\text{from } 5+5) + 8 \ (\text{from } 5+3+2) = 14
$$
Step 2: Total number of possible outcomes
We can win by drawing either 2 or 3 tiles.

For 2 tiles: The number of ways to choose any 2 tiles from 8 is $\binom{8}{2} = 28$.
For 3 tiles: The number of ways to choose any 3 tiles from 8 is $\binom{8}{3} = 56$.

Thus, the total number of possible outcomes is:
$$
28 + 56 = 84
$$
Step 3: Probability of winning
The probability of winning is the ratio of favorable outcomes to total possible outcomes:
$$
P(\text{win}) = \frac{14}{84} = \frac{1}{6}
$$
Is my approach correct? Could there be any other way to improve the calculation?

You can also draw four numbers and not exceed 10…

Your approach is almost correct. The small error is that you are mixing the sample space for different events. What you are intending to do is the following: $\Pr(\text{win}) = \sum_{i = 2}^{8} \Pr(\text{win} \cap {\text{ draw } i \text{ balls}})$. Clearly you can win only if you draw $2$ or $3$ balls. Now you separately compute the probabilities of winning when you have 2 balls and 3 balls and add them. You should be able to do it quickly given you have done most of the work already.

When you calculate probabilities by counting outcomes, you must be sure that all outcome are equally probable. You have not taken into account the order in which the tiles are drawn. Your result is too small, the probability that your first 2 draws are both 5s is $\frac 48 \cdot \frac 37 = \frac 3{14}$, which is greater than $\frac 16$

This exercise is difficult, and your question reveals that you are very far from the good approach. You should try many exercises less difficult than this one. Progress step by step.

@Lourrran, while I understand that everyone has their own style, it would be far more productive if you could offer helpful suggestions rather than resorting to cynicism. A more thoughtful and constructive approach would go a long way in fostering a more positive and collaborative environment.

The safest way to do this is to treat all the tiles as distinguishable and to count equally probable 8-tuples (of which there are $N=8!$)
$$\{5_1, 5_2, 5_3, 5_4, 3_5, 3_6, 2_7, 1_8\}$$
to get the $5+5$ cases you count the 8 tuples whose first two elements have subscript 1, 2, 3, or 4, So the number of 8-tuples is...
$$N_1= 4\cdot 3 \cdot 6!$$
to get the $5+3+2$ cases, the first 3 elements' subscripts must include a 7, one from {5, 6}, and one from {1, 2, 3, 4}. there are $4\times 2 \times 1=8$ ways to choose them and 3! ways to permute the three tiles So the number of 8-tuples is...
$$N_2 = 4\cdot 2 \cdot 3! \cdot 5!$$
So the total probability is...
$$ P = \frac{N_1+N_2}{N}=\frac 5{14}$$

But OP has said $\mathtt{without; replacement}$?

My answer is a "no replacement" answer. Each equally probable outcome corresponds to a permutation of the subscripts 1 to 8, so no tile can be drawn more than once.

Oh, missed the first two etc !

Your attempt was essentially $\dfrac{6+8}{28+56}=\dfrac 16$  as the sum of the number of ways of succeeding in two balls or in three balls, all divided by the sum of the total number of ways of drawing two balls and of drawing three balls, but using a counting approach like this for probability fails when a particular two-ball draw has a different probability compared to a three-ball draw.
Instead you should have $\dfrac{6}{28}+\dfrac{8}{56}=\dfrac{5}{14}$ as the sum of the probabilities of the mutually exclusive events of succeeding in two balls or in three balls.
